# If string contains “T” then remove. After this concat with a time string to form a date within a automapper file

Tags: string, automapper, contain, datetime-parsing

I have two strings. A date string and a time string, these need to be concatenated together to form a valid datetime. The below code works but looks a bit messy and a bit like a hack, is there a better way?

```
.ForMember(dest => dest.ValidFrom, src => src.MapFrom(m => 
                        DateTime.Parse(m.ValidFromDate.Contains("T") ? 
                            m.ValidFromDate.Remove(m.ValidFromDate.LastIndexOf("T", StringComparison.Ordinal) + 1) 
                            : 
                            m.ValidFromDate 
                        + " " + 
                        m.ValidFromTime)))
```

Comment: The code would be a lot easier to read if it was extracted to a method

Comment: I've tried to format it a bit better

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I fixed this in the end:

date/time converter:

```
import moment from 'moment';

export class DateTimeFormat {
    format(date, time) {

        var dateFormatted;

        if (typeof(date) === 'string')
        {
            // Must have come from the DB 
            dateFormatted = date;
        }
        else
        {
            // Must be an object from a calendar etc
            dateFormatted = moment(date).format('DD/MM/YYYY');
        }

        return moment(dateFormatted + 'T' + time, 'DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss');
    }
}
```

Code behind for the form:

```
            this.validator = this.validation.on(this)                    
            .ensure('baseContent.ValidFromDate', (config) => { config.computedFrom(['baseContent.ValidFromDate', 'baseContent.ValidFromTime', 'baseContent.ValidToDate', 'baseContent.ValidToTime']) })
                .if(() => {
                    return this.baseContent.ValidFromDate !== null && this.baseContent.ValidFromTime !== null && this.baseContent.ValidToDate !== null && this.baseContent.ValidToTime !== null })
                    .passes( () => { return this.datetimeformat.format(this.baseContent.ValidFromDate, this.baseContent.ValidFromTime) < this.datetimeformat.format(this.baseContent.ValidToDate, this.baseContent.ValidToTime) })
                    .withMessage('< Valid To')
                .endIf()
```